# Inverse `cherry-pick` operation

Tags: babeljs

I have a repository with the file content. In a branch, I submit some commit to this new feature. Somewhen, I submit some wrong commits and continue my work submitting others, now correct, commits. How can I `cherry-pick` this commit out?

I tried to :

1. checkout to the local `master` branch (`git checkout master`). The previous branch commits remain, as you can see by `git log`);
2. checkout a new branch (`git checkout -b new-branch`)
3. Cherry-pick specific commits (`git cherry-pick commit_sha`)

Answer (score 0):

You need [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), which allows (amongst many other features) selectively applying a set of commits from one branch into another.

I find Tortoise Git's interactive rebase tool is quite easy to understand, if you are in Windows are enjoy using the mouse.

In any other case, I'd still recommend using an external tool such as the [git-interactive-rebase-tool](https://github.com/MitMaro/git-interactive-rebase-tool) command line utility.

Comment: I am a linux user. Your comment is intentionally good, but I have some concerns it is not correct. I have some ideas relating `stash` and `reset`, but it seems a little bit too hard.

Comment: You could also simply cherrypick each commit of interest in a new branch, ommitting the unwanted one. Stash is like a commit in a temporary branch, and reset will loose some commits, so i don't think they will help you in this case

Comment: Well said. Thanks for the hints